# How to add numbering/numbers to Drupal 8 Book Child Pages or Book Outlined Pages or Book Content Pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I am seeking answer for questions is How to add numbering/numbers to Drupal 8 Book Child Pages or Book Outlined Pages or Book Content Pages.

Means, I want to show book content/child pages with numbering as like below image when we are viewing a drupal book (for example URL is mysite.com/book/drupal)

[A book view with content pages with numbering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgMrZ.png)

Can anyone give a answer/solution to above question and note that I want answer for Drupal 8 book module. Your help is really much appreciated. And I want to show numbering to below image as like above image.

[book view and book child/content pages without numbering, and need answer for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajzme.png)

Thanks in advance for answers and answering.